# Fire event only when clicking on an element, and not on its children

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

If I bind a `click` handler to the `body` element, when I click anything on the page the event is triggered. I can check the `event.target` on every click:

```
$("body").on("click", function(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName == "BODY") {
    ...
  }
});
```

but that seem a bit overkill. Is there a way to trigger the event only when clicking the blank area of the body itself?

Comment: I think you mean children rather than siblings. How much of your page body doesn't have another element covering it? It's usually not much at all--a bit of padding at the edges.

Comment: I think you should prevent the `bubbling`!?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`eventPhase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.eventPhase) property of event. A value of `2` means that the event is currently triggering the target element:

```
$("body").on("click", function(event) {
    //Cancel if not at target
    if (event.eventPhase != 2) return;

    //Other Code Here
});
```

Fiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/o0yptmmp/

Comment: Thats a.w.e.s.o.m.e!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it if you check on every click if the element clicked has a body parent. If the condition is false, you are clicking the body:

```
$("body").on("click", function(event) {
  if ($(this).parents('body').length == 0) {
     //Do something
  }
});
```

In my opinion it's not a good practice, but it depends on your code and project.

Comment: The way you explain it, any nested element inside the body will trigger the click, as well as clicking on the `<html>` tag or the `window`, which is the entire page. Your code, however, only breaks on the `<html>` and `window` cases.

Answer (score 1):

You should put an

```
event.stopPropagation()
```

on all children you want to not `bubble` up.

#### jQuery Docs: http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/.

Comment: This is more than just _overkill_ (to use the OP own words).

Comment: @MelanciaUK Yeah, it is a small line to downvote. %)P