# Jquery. toggleclass to not toggle on click on child

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using :

```
$("#cart").click(function(e){
    $('#cart').load('index.php?route=module/cart #cart > *');
    var e=window.event||e;
    $("#cart").toggleClass("active");
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(document).click(function(e){
       $("#cart").removeClass("active");

       $('#cart').live('mouseleave', function() {

       });  
    });
});
```

now the problem is that whenever I click on a child of `#cart`it toggles the class, which I don't want. How can I make it only toggle when I click on `#cart` and not on the child ?

Comment: This is not enough context, toggleClass() toggles the class but does not affect event binding/handling, please post more code so we can see what's going on.

Comment: I updated the code, it's all that I'm using for it.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26150500/fire-event-only-when-clicking-on-an-element-and-not-on-its-children/26150771

Comment: That looks good enough to get you answers, but while we are here in the comment section, make sure you scrap that live() call with .on() if you are using an up-to-date jQuery build.

Answer (score 0):

To check if an event handler has been called because of event bubbling, compare `this` to `event.target` within the event handler:

```
$('#cart').on('click', function(event){
  if(this === event.target){
    // $('#cart') was clicked 
  } else {
   // event has bubbled up from a descendant of $('#cart')
  }
});
```